# How can I move place in the company but no need to move the PC

Tags: cloud

How can I move place in the company but no need to move the PC? That is the same as I have the cloud in the company and each employee moving position in company but no need to move current PC.

Comment: And how is it related to programming!

Comment: Yeah, That is good a question. I see I can not work out the office with a new PC in case I oversea because My Pc have the environment for programming. So I things it related now.